# Deploy new image in Docker Compose stack without downtime

Tags: docker, docker-compose, high-availability

We have a multi-container application, which uses a [microservices](https://smartbear.com/learn/api-design/what-are-microservices/) architecture, running in Docker Compose.

When I make code changes to the web app, for example, I need to rebuild the image with new code, then run it again in my compose stack, without any downtime.

Here is the current sequence of events that we are using:

1. Make changes to app code
2. Rebuild image
3. Push image(to docker hub)
4. `docker-compose down`
5. `docker-compose up`

After running `docker-compose down`, all apps go down. Then `docker-compose up` brings the whole stack back up.

Is there a way to redeploy individual images in Docker Compose without any downtime, and without bringing down the entire application stack?

Answer (score 6):

You can avoid to put down everything at the same time (`docker-compose down`), just with something like this:

```
docker-compose pull --parallel
docker-compose up --force-recreate <specific-service-name1>
```

This will pull & stop & recreate (run) your `<specific-service-name1>` containers, and won't touch any other container.
Later you can deploy the rest:

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate <specific-service-name2>
docker-compose up --force-recreate <specific-service-name3>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is still some downtime while recreating the container. If I increase the replicas to > 1 for all services in compose, is there a way in compose to `--force-recreate` in a rolling fashion, to eliminate the downtime?

Comment: It seems quite possible but using "docker service". *The --update-delay flag configures the time delay between updates to a service task or sets of tasks* https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/rolling-update/